# Aurelia: Dep. Injection on derived classes not possible? (or what am I doing wrong?!)

Tags: aurelia, systemjs

The scenario: I have two derived classes that both extend the ActionBase class as follows. I want to use DI for both derived classes. But both classes have different dependencies. That should be possible, right? So what am I doing wrong? In both cases the injected instances/modules are 'undefined'. Any help/hint appreciated.

```
/*
 * Base class for Actions
 */

export class ActionBase {

  type;

  constructor(type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}





/*
 * Derived Class: InsertAction
 */

import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ActionBase} from './ActionBase';
import {PomManager} from '../manager/PomManager';

@inject(PomManager)
export class InsertAction extends ActionBase {

  pomManager;

  constructor(pomManager) {
    super("insert");
    this.pomManager = pomManager;
    console.log("[InsertAction:constructor] pomManager: ", this.pomManager); // undefined
  }
}





/*
 * Derived Class: RenderAction
 */

import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {ActionBase} from './ActionBase';
import {AnotherManager} from '../manager/AnotherManager';

@inject(AnotherManager)
export class RenderAction extends ActionBase {

  anotherManager;

  constructor(anotherManager) {
    super("render");
    this.anotherManager = anotherManager;
    console.log("[RenderAction:constructor] anotherManager: ", this.anotherManager); // undefined
  }
}
```

Comment: That should be possible. Are you sure that `./ActionBase` is the correct path of ActionBase class file?

Comment: Yes. That part works just fine (the snippet above is of course not in a single file). Methods are inherited and working as expected... It only works if I inject the dependencies on base class level... but not all derived classes have the same dependencies... so that is not an option. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supported. Look at this working example where Action1 and Action2 extend BaseAction and each take different dependencies.

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=0efabf77c649f41981dcde753fdc542c**

**app.js**

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection'
import {Action1, Action2} from './classes'

@inject(Action1, Action2)
export class App {
  constructor(a1, a2){
    this.message = "look at console output";
    console.log("a1",  a1.dep.constructor.name);
    console.log("a2",  a2.dep.constructor.name); 
  }
}
```

**classes.js**

```js
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection'
export class Action1Dependency {}
export class Action2Dependency {}

export class ActionBase{

}

@inject(Action1Dependency)
export class Action1 extends ActionBase{
  constructor(dep){
    super();
    this.dep = dep;
  }
}

@inject(Action2Dependency)
export class Action2 extends ActionBase{
  constructor(dep){
    super();
    this.dep = dep;
  }
}
```